# Having multiple slide templates in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I'd like to create a presentation using LaTeX beamer, that has two different sort of slide templates/layouts: one for slides with a background image and one layout/template for slides without a specified background image.

Is there any trick to do this using beamer?

Comment: Have you tried asking here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I boils down to putting `\usebackgroundtemplate` before each `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific background image for a single slide, just put an

`{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background.jpg}}`

directly before your `\begin{frame}`.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done via a new frame option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{mydefault}{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}
}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{fullimage}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[mydefault]%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{fullimage}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[fullimage]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  left
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[fullimage]
  right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  is left again
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to generate two copies of the presentation simultaneously.  To do this, you use some low-level tex commands and several files.

In `Presentation.tex` you might have

```
%&pdftex
\relax
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -synctex=1 PresentationWithBG.tex}
\relax
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -synctex=1 PresentationWithoutBG.tex}
\end
```

That is the only file you will actually have to run latex on, which you do with `pdftex --shell-escape Presentation.tex`.  But you will also need the following.

In `PresentationWithBG.tex` (note that you don't actually need `\usebackgroundtemplate` before each frame):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{<your_background_fig>}}
\input{PresentationContent}
```

In `PresentationWithoutBG.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{PresentationContent}
```

In `PresentationContent.tex`:

```
\begin{document}
[All your actual presentation goes here...]
\end{document}
```

When you run `pdftex --shell-escape Presentation.tex`, you'll get `PresentationWithBG.pdf` and `PresentationWithoutBG.pdf`.

Note that `%&pdftex` in `Presentation.tex` makes sure that whichever version of TeX is running switches into the right mode.  You could actually run it with `pdflatex`.